# ffmpeg library is not working

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have got `FFmpeg` compiled (`libffmpeg.so`) on Android. Now I have to build either an application like RockPlayer or use existing Android multimedia framework to invoke `FFmpeg` along with video playing.

Do you have steps / procedures / code / example on integrating `FFmpeg` on Android / StageFright?

> Can you please guide me on how can I use this library for multimedia
>   playback?

I already did rendering, mixing.

Comment: You can use `WritingMinds` `FFmpeg` here is [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342834/javacv-in-android/42343111#42343111)

Comment: Highlighted main question.

Answer (score 1):

1. compile `'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'`   add this to gradle

   2. Add this inside onCreate :

      **`ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());`**

      (Declare `FFmpeg ffmpeg;` first)
   3. Load library :    `loadFFMpegBinary();`
2. Code to add audio to video using ffmpeg:

call function using  `execFFmpegBinaryShortest(null);`

**

```
private void execFFmpegBinaryShortest(final String[] command) {
    final File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/videoaudiomerger/"+"Vid"+"output"+i1+".mp4");

   String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i", selectedVideoPath,"-i",audiopath,"-map","1:a","-map","0:v","-codec","copy","-shortest",outputFile.getPath()};


            try {

                ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String s) {
                        System.out.println("on failure----"+s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {
                        System.out.println("on success-----"+s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String s) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg "+command);
                        System.out.println("Started---"+s);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {


                        //Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                        System.out.println("Start----");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        System.out.println("Finish-----");


                    }
                });
            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                // do nothing for now
                System.out.println("exceptio :::"+e.getMessage());
            }


            }
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Download ffmpeg from here: http://bambuser.com/opensource.  It contains scripts to build ffmpeg for android.
Modify build.sh. Replace "com.bambuser.broadcaster" with your package name.  You also need to set the ffmpeg flags to enable to codecs you're interested in.
Run build.sh, and copy the build/ffmpeg directory into your apps jni/lib directory.
Use fasaxc's makefile from the SO post.
Create a native.c file in your jni directory and a java wrapper.  To start with you can model it after hello-jni in NDK samples (/samples/hello-jni).
Include headers in your native.c file like this: #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h".  And call the functions you need: avcodec_register_all(), etc...
Include the native libraries in your root activity by adding: static { System.loadLibraries(""); }